# Wordpress plugin to remove content rendering

Tags: wordpress

I want my plugin to stop wordpress from rendering the page.
I've already stopped it from rendering the footer and head using

`remove_all_actions('wp_footer', 1);
remove_all_actions('wp_head', 1);`

But I can't find something to do this for the content. How can I stop the content from rendering?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `the_content` hook and return an empty string: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_the_content', 99 );

function filter_the_content( $content ) {
    return "";
}
```

Comment: I still get content when doing this. I call the methods you mentioned in a method which is called by this code `add_action( 'wp', 'checkForCachedHtml', 1 );`

Comment: interesting... maybe try adding priority 99 as in the latest edit?

Comment: can you try calling the add_filter outside of the `add_action`?